# Printing an array of numbers on a window

Tags: java, graphics

Hello I am new to java graphics and just experimenting with things but I am puzzled with how I can display the numbers in an array on my created window? I am not sure if it works the same as text or not?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class area extends JFrame{


    int[] myArray;
    myArray = new int[3];
    myArray[0] = 1;
    myArray[1] = 2;
    myArray[2] = 3;

JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
{
    area.append(myArray[i]+"\n");
}
add(area);  


public static void main(String args[]) {

area gui = new area(); 
gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
gui.setSize(400,200);
gui.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Show us, what did you try to do

Comment: A GUI is nothing like displaying text on the console. Start by reading the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). You could display the numbers in a JTextArea, JLIst or create a bunch of JLabels. The choice is yours.

Comment: To change your array to a String, there are two obvious options. The first is to iterate through every element in the array, concatenating as you go: `for (int i: myArray) str += i +" ";` The second option is to use Arrays.toString(myArray) and remove all the ['s, ,'s, and ]'s: `Arrays.toString(myArray).replaceAll("[\\[,\\]]", "");` The latter is faster for long arrays, the former for short arrays (If you are doing it many times in a row).

Answer (score 2):

Use a JTextArea and you can save your array as a string

```
String text;
for(int w : array) {
   w=Integer.toString(w);
   text+=w;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JTextArea.

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
    ta.append(array[i]+"\n");
}
add(ta);
```

Comment: well I tried messing with JTextArea and I am just getting a whole mess of errors but I am assuming its just a small thing I am missing. I'll post my code above and maybe you can teach how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an IDE like eclipse? If not might help. Looks like part of your code is in the wrong place. Instead of constructor or init method its just below the var declerations. IDE will help you with that. Also go thru (patiently) some more basic tutorials and look at small existing code.

Following code worked for me small edit to yours near //constructor

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    //put in a file called area.java
    public class area extends JFrame{


            int[] myArray;
            JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
     //constructor 
     area(){
            myArray = new int[3];
            myArray[0] = 1;
            myArray[1] = 2;
            myArray[2] = 3;




    for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
    {
            area.append(i + " " + myArray[i]+"\n");
    }
    add(area);

       }
    public static void main(String args[]) {

         area gui = new area();
         gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         gui.setSize(400,200);
         gui.setVisible(true);
       }
    }
```